# iPad: 5 feeds into split view

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, communication, ipad, pushviewcontroller

So I have an iPhone app that consist of a tabbarcontroller, 5 tableviews (one for each rss feed) and a webview to show the selected news post.

I want to create a iPad app that does the same. How do I have 5 different tableviews in the master view (left view) of the split view?

I found this description of an split view in a tabbar, but many forums does not recommend this method.
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=12525197

Alternative:
I would live with 5 buttons in a toolbar, but that would be in the detail view. How should I communicate the button press event to the master view?

Or have I not seen the smart functionalities the split view offers???

Really hope someone can help me.. I used a week of figuring out this structure!
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

move the five rss feeds from the tab bar to the left tableview, the user can then select the rss feed, which will push the rss feed into the left tableview. upon article selection it will load to the detail view. much like twitterific does on the ipad with multiple accounts.

Comment: thanks.. I did that, but my problem was when I push the view from a tableview list of the 5 feeds to the selected feed in the left view, then how do I push the information from the new pushed feed view to the details view. ?

Comment: in the past i have used one ViewController for the first left view, and another for the second. the first VC pushes into the left navigation controller, and the second VC pushes into the detail view.